# png files not readable after extracting mbtiles

Tags: openmaptiles

I need to run with tiles on an offline system.
I like the idea of being able to download .mbtiles files, 
and extract the tiles.

I downloaded a data set and tried to extract tiles using mb-util.
When I try to extract tiles from the .mbtiles file.
The .png files are not readable.

This isn't a permissions problem.

The .png files don't appear to be .png files.

Any idea why this doesn't work?
Is is not supported?
Does it have something to do with the free data set I'm testing with?

I'm going to have a difficult time getting my company to spend money for
something, if I can't prove the data is valid.

Comment: I'm using the docker container to serve the mbtiles, this seems to work as advertised.  I was able to determine the problem with .png files.  The data is stored as .pbf, not png, so you need some way to render or convert the pbf to png.  Using the docker container is an easier way to deal with this.  I think this issue can be closed.